# Datetime compare based on previous date in PHP

Tags: mysql

How can I compare selection based on previous date? For example:

```
Item          Start         End
------        ------        ------
Football      2015-02-03    2015-03-03
```

I want, if any user want to add Football again user can't choose any date between 2015-02-03 to 2015-03-03. He have to choose a future date from both start & end. How can I do that?

Comment: Use just that, `BETWEEN` with a conditional statement.

Comment: Thanks .. but will you explain little more please?

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$newdat = new input date by user

```
"SELECT * FROM `Football` WHERE ('$newdate' BETWEEN `startDate` AND `endDate`)"
```

if it exist between any start and end date then you can return false or anything